# Update entity with JPA 1.0 and Hibernate after change database value

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I'm working on a Java project with EJB 3.0. I'm using JPA 1.0 and Hibernate as persistence provider.
The problem is: when I change a value in the database, I can't see the change until I restart the application server (JBoss 5.x).

The question: there is a way to update immediately, without restart the web server?
I can't use method as `refresh()` or `clear()`.

The 2nd level cache is already disabled with these property:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
```

Comment: How are you changing value in database, add relevant code & JBoss is application server.

Comment: How are you reading the value? if it is being read from a different persistence context every time, you should already see the updated value after disabling second level cache...